# Unit test case for loading properties file

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am trying to write unit test case for the following piece of code.

```
public static String maskUri(String uri) {
...
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("application.properties");
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            try
            {
                prop.load(resource.getInputStream());
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                //Log the exception
            }
...
}
```

Actual code works fine. The problem is it looks for application.properties while executing the junit test case and fails as it couldn't find the file.
Can someone please suggest pointers on how to proceed with this?

Is it possible to add another properties file and use it for test cases? As the file name is directly given in the source code, it always looks for application.properties only.

Is there a way to dynamically change the property file like to use application.properties for core functionality and application-test.properties for Junit?

Comment: Looks like you are working around Spring Boot. What is it you are trying to test?

Comment: I am adding some patterns in application.properties and checking them to mask the URI, like if URI contains the pattern of MSISDN, it will replace it with *. I need to write junit for testing this functionality.

Comment: And why would you need to load the properties for that? Specify some patterns in the test to test the functionality. Currently it more looks like you want to validate your configuration instead of the correct working of the masking.